# protobuf-net serialization without attributes

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have an assembly with DataContracts and I need to generate .proto schema for it to be able to exchange the data with java system. The DataContracts code can be changed but I cannot add `[ProtoContract]` and `[ProtoMember]` attributes in it because it will result in protobuf-net assembly dependency. We use WCF in C# parts of the system so we would not want to have dependency on proto-buf assembly in most of C# projects that don't work with java system.

On the protobuf-net site in a [GettingStarted](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted#Don%27t_Like_Attributes?) section it's said that:

> Don't Like Attributes?
>   In v2, everything that can be done with attributes can also be configured at runtime via RuntimeTypeModel.

However I've no clue how to actually configure serialization without attributes and I haven't seen any examples of that.

I'm trying to do

```
[DataContract]
public class MyEntity
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public String PropertyA { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public int PropertyB { get; set; }
}

RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(MyEntity), false);

string proto = Serializer.GetProto<MyEntity>();
```

And get the following as the value of `proto`

```
package ProtobufTest;

message MyEntity {
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clarification: most of this answer relates to the pre-edit question, where `false` was passed to `RuntimeTypeModel.Add(...)`

---

I've used your exact code (I inferred that this was in `namespace ProtobufTest`, but the rest was copy/paste from the question) with r2.0.0.640 (the current NuGet deployment), and I get:

```
package ProtobufTest;

message MyEntity {
   optional string PropertyA = 1;
   optional int32 PropertyB = 2 [default = 0];
}
```

Further, you get the *exact* same result even if you remove the `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(...)` line.

It is unclear to me why you are seeing something different - can you clarify:

- which protobuf-net version you are using *exactly*
- if those `[DataContract]` / `[DataMember]` attributes are the `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` ones, or your own (sorry if that seems a bizarre question)

To answer the question fully: if you couldn't have any attributes (and the ones you have are just fine), you could also do:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(MyEntity), false)
    .Add(1, "PropertyA")
    .Add(2, "PropertyB");
```

which would configure `PropertyA` as key 1, and `PropertyB` as key 2.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! I use the same version. The second parameter in my `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(MyEntity), ...)` was actually `false`. With `true` or without that call at all I get the same result as you do.

Comment: @Mike ah, right; yes, that `false` means "don't look at the attributes", which includes not looking at the `DataMember(Order=n)` attributes. If you pass `false`, you need to configure it *manually* - which is what I have done in the last example above. If you want to use the `DataMember(Order=n)` attributes: say `true`

Comment: By the way, it would be nice to have those `.Add(1, "PropertyA")` parts to accept Expression as the second parameter for the strong-typing and compiler checking :) This will ease working with non-attributed types.

Comment: @Mike well, you could always add an extension method; I've deliberately limited the dependencies - mostly it only currently uses 2.0, and 3.0 if you want the WCF support; heck, it will even compile for .NET 1.1 if you really want. Adding a 3.5 dependency *just* for `Expression` seems a bit overkill.

Comment: Makes total sense. The extension is pretty trivial to implement myself.